# Firefox wont reset jquery created element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firefox

This probably is a duplicate but I don't know how to express what is happening in a title description.
I have an image element which i delete and re-create with the click of a button, basically i apply filters with php to an image, and delete the previous element to replace it with the new image to display the new filter.

the code to create the element:

```
function pictureReset(data) {
    $( ".filteredImg" ).remove();
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("class", "filteredImg");
    elem.setAttribute("height", "328");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "");
    elem.src = 'contest/filtered_'+tempFilePath;
    document.getElementById("filteredImgContainer").appendChild(elem);
}
```

the code to apply the filter: (i have several filters but the code is the same, they just call a different php file

```
$('#sepia').click(function () {
    var filePathName = tempFilePath;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/sepia.php',
        dataType : 'text',
        data: {
            FilePath : filePathName
        },
        success: function (data) {
            pictureReset();
        }
    }).done(function(response){console.log(response);});
});
```

now the problem is **although it works *fine* on chrome**, i.e. when i click the button the old image is removed and replaced with the new filtered image, on firefox although it refreshes, somehow it retrieves the old image (even though it doesn't exist because on the server if i retrieve the image the filter is applied), and displays the old filter instead of the new one. Any ideas as to why this is happening??

Comment: Try appending a random argument at the end of the new image path just like we have in url. Something like "test2432", any random number.

Comment: you mean the line `elem.src = 'contest/filtered_'+tempFilePath;` to replace it with something like `elem.src = 'contest/filtered_'+tempFilePath+randomNumber;` ??

Comment: Yeah. Let's say your image path is :"/images/sample.png" then just replace that with "/images/sample.png?test=12345" . Try this.

Comment: @alexandros Ya, try: `elem.src = 'contest/filtered_'+tempFilePath+'?'+ $.now();`

Comment: hmm, `tempFilePath` is set from a php file that has nothing to do with filtering but just uploads the file. The steps: i upload the file, get the `filepath`, apply the filter to the `filepath` and edit the `filePath to filtered_filepath`, all filteres are applied to the new `filePath filtered_filepath`, so what you are suggesting is not that easy, because i will change the php that uploads to return `filepath+randomno`, but it will still be the same since filtering php files dont change the filepath

Comment: I appended this `+'?'+ $.now();` and it worked! can you please explain what happened cause this looks like magic to me? :)

Comment: It's because of the firefox caching the images. When you change the src of images, firefox removes the cached image and reloads it

Comment: cheers to both of you :D

Comment: You can further improve your code. I am adding a answer to this. You can have a look at it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from adding the parameters, you can also improve the code. Since you are already using jQuery.

You can replace this code:

```
function pictureReset(data) {
  $( ".filteredImg" ).remove();
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  elem.setAttribute("class", "filteredImg");
  elem.setAttribute("height", "328");
  elem.setAttribute("alt", "");
  elem.src = 'contest/filtered_'+tempFilePath;
  document.getElementById("filteredImgContainer").appendChild(elem);
}
```

With:

```
 function pictureReset(data) {
    var elem = $('<img class="filteredImg" alt="" style="height:328px;" src="contest/filtered_' + tempFilePath + '?t="' + $.now() + ' />');
    $("#filteredImgContainer img.filteredImg").replaceWith(elem);
}
```

I used [jQuery replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) for this code.

Comment: thank you for the solution and the new jquery trick! :D I love it when 6-7 lines of code become 2 :) +1 for simplicity :D

Comment: That's what jQuery can do for you ;)